# Force windows 10 to save by defailt on another folder

Tags: windows-10, my-documents

I would like to force Windows 10 every time I try to save a new document or file to not show me by default this My Documents folder but rather a subfolder that I have named MyLibrary. I tried already changing in registry the %USERPROFILE%\Documents to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\MyLibrary but the problem was that applications like Outlook did not really started after that and I had to turn it back to the default value.

I also found this website: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-save-location-windows-10;
that option only allows you to pick the hard disk and not the exact folder.

Comment: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-change-your-default-save-locations-windows-10